# Redis-cluster setup on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redis-server

i want to setup multi-node redis-server cluster on ubuntu 20 using docker

i am getting documents for single node redis-server cluster

can anyone share me the commands or the links for setting up multinode redis-server cluster

Answer (score 2):

You can find instructions [here](https://redis.io/docs/management/scaling/#requirements-to-create-a-redis-cluster).

For example, to create a minimal cluster with 3 masters:

1. Create 3 directories (e.g., `7000`, `7001`, `7002`).
2. In each directory, create a `redis.conf` file and add the following directives:

```
port 7000
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
```

Don't forget to change the port in each file.

3. cd to each directory and run:

```
redis-server ./redis.conf
```

4. Run:

```
redis-cli --cluster create 127.0.0.1:7000 127.0.0.1:7001 127.0.0.1:7002 --cluster-replicas 0
```